# Can list comprehensions make groups?

Tags: python, collections, group-by, aggregate, list-comprehension

I have a list that looks like

```
[(1,2,5),(2,10,13),(5,24,56),(1,8,10),(2,3,11)]
```

How can I produce a dictionary by grouping by first element of tuples and finding `min` element in second elements and `max` element in third elements:

```
{1:(2,10),2:(3,13),5:{24,56}]
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a list comprehension (or rather a dictionary comprehension) here? Especially when you have to produce both a minimum *and* a maximum value, the expression will get ugly and large fast. A proper loop will make the code a lot more readable, *and* more efficient as you then don't have to sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, if you first *sort* on the grouping element, then use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your elements and test for minimum and maximum values. Because the groups are generators, you need to jump through an extra hoop to turn that into a list you can reuse for the `min()` and `max()` functions:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = {k: (min(item[1] for item in gv), max(item[2] for item in gv))
         for k, g in groupby(sorted(inputlist, key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))
         for gv in (list(g),)}
```

Note that this sorts (O(NlogN)) then loops over each group twice to find the minimum and maximum of each group, adding another 2N to the total.

The additional `for gv in (list(g),)` loop assigns a list to `gv` containing all elements from the `g` group.

The simple loop version would be:

```
result = {}
for key, v1, v2 in inputlist:
    minimum, maximum = result.get(key, (float('inf'), float('-inf')))
    if v1 < minimum:
        minimum = v1
    if v2 > maximum:
        maximum = v2
    result[key] = (minimum, maximum)
```

This is a straightforward O(N) loop, and more readable to boot.

Demo of the two approaches:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> inputlist = [(1,2,5),(2,10,13),(5,24,56),(1,8,10),(2,3,11)]
>>> {k: (min(item[1] for item in gv), max(item[2] for item in gv))
...          for k, g in groupby(sorted(inputlist, key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))
...          for gv in (list(g),)}
{1: (2, 10), 2: (3, 13), 5: (24, 56)}
```

and

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for key, v1, v2 in inputlist:
...     minimum, maximum = result.get(key, (float('inf'), float('-inf')))
...     if v1 < minimum:
...         minimum = v1
...     if v2 > maximum:
...         maximum = v2
...     result[key] = (minimum, maximum)
... 
>>> result
{1: (2, 10), 2: (3, 13), 5: (24, 56)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: ll = [(1,2,5),(2,10,13),(5,24,56),(1,8,10),(2,3,11)]

In [10]: {k[0]: ( min([kk[1] for kk in ll if kk[0] == k[0]]), max([kk[2] for kk in ll if kk[0] == k[0]]) ) for k in ll}
Out[10]: {1: (2, 10), 2: (3, 13), 5: (24, 56)}
```

or

```
In [11]: {k[0]: (v[0], v[-1]) for k in ll for v in [sorted([x for y in [[kk[1], kk[2]] for kk in ll if kk[0] == k[0] ] for  x in y])] }
Out[11]: {1: (2, 10), 2: (3, 13), 5: (24, 56)}
```

Comment: This'll work, but will show quadratic behaviour and so isn't useful for long lists.